# Building Listview in MVC using inputs from the controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listview, razor

**Problem Statement:**

I'm trying to build a listview using the inputs from the controls like textbox and dropdownlist. Simply i want to add/remove data from listview without interacting with db.

Currently i can bind data to listview from db in 3 ways:

- Using IEnumerable model items with foreach loop
- Using Grid.MVC3 dll from codeplex using bootstrap
- JQGrid (which is not free)

But in above all the 3 cases i'm interacting with db for binding data. My problem is that i want to add/remove data from textbox/dropdown to listview without interacting with db

Actually i tried with Listbox but here i can accomplish only one column,actually i'm having 2 columns and want to display headers for the added columns in listview.

*How to achive this in **MVC Razor** which is very simple in Windows/ASP applications??*

*Any solutions/suggestions for my problem???*